# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in line 34

Tags: javascript, html

I've already searched for my problem, but the solutions were not able to help me.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</title>  
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</h1> 
  <button type="button" onclick = "start();">Start</button> 
  <button type = "button" onclick = "fertig();">Fertig!</button>
  <input id = "erginput" type = "number" >
  <br>
  <label id = "rn1"></label>  
  <label id = "multiplication"><label>
  <label id = "rn2"></label>  

<script>

function start() 

{   
//var anzahl = 0
//while (anzahl < 20){

var randomnumber1 = getrn();
var randomnumber2 = getrn();
document.getElementById("rn1").innerHTML = randomnumber1;
document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = "x";
document.getElementById("rn2").innerHTML = randomnumber2;
//}
}

function getrn(){
var min = 3;
var max = 10;
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
return randomnumber;
}</script>
</body>
```

I thought that the null is because randomnumber2 oder rn2 is not defined since I saw that mistake in other codes, but here they're both defined, aren't they?

Thanks in advance!

Ji W

Comment: your multiplication label is not closed with </label>..you missed '/'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had invalid markup! `</label>` was not closed..

```js
function start() {
  var randomnumber1 = getrn();
  var randomnumber2 = getrn();
  document.getElementById("rn1").innerHTML = randomnumber1;
  document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = "x";
  document.getElementById("rn2").innerHTML = randomnumber2;
}

function getrn() {
  var min = 3;
  var max = 10;
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  return randomnumber;
}
```

```html
<h1>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</h1> 
<button type="button" onclick="start();">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="fertig();">Fertig!</button>
<input id="erginput" type="number">
<br>
<label id="rn1"></label>
<label id="multiplication"></label>
<label id="rn2"></label>
```